# How to display an object of objects without repetitions on the site

Tags: javascript, node.js

The problem is this, I need to display a list of users in a modal window, but the problem is that the list of all names is constantly duplicated there, how can this be avoided? And to be equally visible to all users on the page
Here is the code how it works:

```
const addUserToModalWindow = () => {
    const contentWindow = document.querySelector(".usersList");
    socket.on('users', (users) => {
        for (let user of Object.values(users)) {
            contentWindow.innerHTML += `<div>• ${user.name}</div>`;
        }
    });
};
```

Here are the photos of what is duplicated (there is no duplication on the second page, if you open the third, then duplication will be on the second and so on)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered deleting the previous entries with `contentWindow.innerHTML = "";` before appending new ones? Alternatively, start with an empty string, add you users there, then set the `innerHTML` only a single time. Mutating `innerHTML` several times is not very performant.

Comment: I don't get it, can you show me an example?

Comment: Add @SebastianSimon's code he mentioned right before your `for` loop. You never clear the list before adding all the names again.

Comment: It’s really not difficult. `let userList = "";` before the loop, `userList +=`…`;` inside the loop, `contentWindow.innerHTML = userList;` after the loop.

Comment: I’d do it with static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods), and use a proper `<ul>` with `<li>`s instead of a series of `<div>`s. Assuming `.userList` is a `<ul>`: `socket.on("users", (users) => document.querySelector(".usersList").replaceChildren(...Object.values(users).map({ name } => Object.assign(document.createElement("li"), { textContent: name }))));`. Just make sure `.on` is only called once.